# Validity of combinatorics method

Tags: combinatorics

There are 4 heterosexual couples to be seated in a circle. How many ways can they sit such that no couple is together and genders alternate?

I simply pair up the couples incorrectly in $3!$ ways - if • is male and # is female, it will be four sets of •#. Then fix two couples and there are $2!$ ways to insert the other two; the $2$ ways allows for any accidental pairing when •{# •}#

Is this naive? It gives me the correct answer but the suggested solution is doing (unrestricted alternate - cases where 1,2,3,4 couples together)

I want to check whether my answer of $12$ was rightly deduced or it is just a coincidence that i get $12$

I am sure about the $3!$ but I sort of FORCED the $2!$ to happen as you can see with my vague explanation "allows for any accidental pairing (to be avoided)"

If there's an even better way, please answer! Especially if its a creative/insightful method, I don't care if its long or short.

Comment: Your explanation of what you did is not clear, which makes it difficult to assess whether your method is valid.  The problem can be done with the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle or by doing casework if you first seat the women, then insert the men so that man sits next to his partner.

Comment: It's not clear because I don't fully understand what I did myself. :( I guess it is purely coincidental then

Comment: Upon rereading my comment, I realized I did not explain my alternate method clearly.  Seat the four women, leaving a seat between each pair of women for the men.  Label the women.  Pick a woman.  Seat her partner in one of the two open seats that are not next to her.  Arrange the remaining men for each such choice so that no man is next to his partner.

Comment: is this the inclusion/exclusion method or cases?

Comment: The method in my second comment is casework.